# Не в то время отправляется сообщение

Tags: c++, telegram-bot, arduino

Делаю датчик влажности с выводом данных в Telegram, вроде все работает, НО сообщение с данными о влажности (newMsg) отправляется не сразу при запросе в Telegram, а когда срабатывает цикл loop, т.е. получается так:

1. я делаю запрос в Telegram
2. Программа считывает сообщение и ждет, когда loop узнает влажность
3. Выводится влажность вместе с loop

Как можно исправить?

```
#define WIFI_SSID "ssid"
#define WIFI_PASS "pass"
#define BOT_TOKEN "token"
    
#include <FastBot.h>
#include <GyverHTU21D.h>
GyverHTU21D htu;
FastBot bot(BOT_TOKEN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  htu.begin();
  bot.attach(newMsg);
  connectWiFi();
  bot.setChatID("id");
  bot.sendMessage("Hello! Let's check the humidity!");
}
 

  


void loop() {
  bot.tick();
  htu.requestHumidity();                    // Запрашиваем преобразование
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(htu.getHumidity());
  if (htu.getHumidity() < 30){
    bot.sendMessage("Low humidity");
    
  }

  else if (htu.getHumidity() > 60){
    bot.sendMessage("High humidity");
    
    }
    delay(10000);
  }

void newMsg(FB_msg& msg) { 
  // ответить
  htu.requestHumidity();                    // Запрашиваем преобразование
  delay(100);
  if (htu.readHumidity()) {
    Serial.println("Hum");
    Serial.println(htu.getHumidity());
  }
  
} 
void connectWiFi() {
  delay(2000);
  
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    
    if (millis() > 15000) ESP.restart();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Может задержка в 10 секунд все тормозит?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, желаемое поведение, что вы подразумеваете под "исправить"?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов нужно, чтобы СРАЗУ при получении нового сообщения выводилась влажность. То, что происходит - в вопросе (кажется, тут нужна многопоточность)

Comment: вообще да, она, но мне нужно, чтобы задержка работала только с циклом loop, а не со всей программой

Comment: loop - это и есть вся программа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если стоит задача на arduino выполнять несколько задач через фиксированные (но отличающиеся для каждой задачи) интервалы времени, то общий подход такой (далее по тексту слово `task` заменить на название задачи):

Для каждой задачи заводятся переменная `unsigned long task_time`, содержащая последнее значение времени запуска данной задачи и константа `unsigned long task_period`, содержащая интервал запуска

Каждое задание желательно оформить в виде отдельной функции `task_proc()`.

В начале цикла loop() в переменную `unsigned long current_time` сохраняем значение `millis()` — текущее время в миллисекундах.

Далее для каждого задания в цикле добавляется такой блок

```
if (current_time - task_time >= task_period)
{
        task_time = current_time;   
        task_proc();
}
```

Соответственно у вас будет две задачи:

1. Вывод влажности в Serial раз в 10*1000 миллисекунд (`task` заменить на, например, `serial_task`)
2. Опрос бота раз в 3600 миллисекунд, это число из описания используемой вами библиотеки Гайвера (`task` заменить на, например, `bot_task`)

Дополнительно конкретно в вашем проекте я бы сделал следующее:

Вынес бы инициализацию и чтение влажности отдельно, пусть выполняется каждый цикл.

```
htu.requestHumidity();
delay(100);
htu.readHumidity();
```

А в обеих функциях выводил бы кэшированное значение `htu.getHumidity()` без предварительного чтения, так как оно уже подготовлено.